# Difference between facebook Hydra's + and ++ operators

Tags: python

If you already been following some of the best practices in Deep Learning, [Facebook's Hydra](https://hydra.cc/docs/1.0/intro/) might be a familiar name to you. Going through the [Hydra Documentation](https://hydra.cc/docs/advanced/override_grammar/basic/), I came across two important operators *+* and *++*. The documents mentions the use of these operators as follows:

```html
Appending a config value : +foo.bar=value
Appending or overriding a config value : ++foo.bar=value
```

I need some help understanding these operators, as using them in the code technically makes no difference in the overall output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we have the following simple hydra app:

```
├── config.yaml
└── my_app.py
```

```py
# my_app.py
import hydra
from omegaconf import OmegaConf, DictConfig

@hydra.main(".", "config")
def app(cfg: DictConfig):
    print(OmegaConf.to_yaml(cfg))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app()
```

```yaml
# config.yaml
a:
  b: c
```

```
$ python my_app.py
a:
  b: c
```

Let's take a look at the four methods of "Modifying the Config Object" from the docs page you linked:

- Overriding a config value: `foo.bar=value`
- Appending a config value: `+foo.bar=value`
- Appending or overriding a config value: `++foo.bar=value`
- Removing a config value: `~foo.bar`, `~foo.bar=value`

---

##### Overriding a config value:

```
$ python my_app.py a.b=y
a:
  b: y
```

```
$ python my_app.py a.x=y
Could not override 'a.x'.
To append to your config use +a.x=y
Key 'x' is not in struct
    full_key: a.x
    object_type=dict
```

##### Appending a config value:

```
$ python my_app.py +a.b=y
Could not append to config. An item is already at 'a.b'.
Either remove + prefix: 'a.b=y'
Or add a second + to add or override 'a.b': '++a.b=y'
...
```

```
$ python my_app.py +a.x=y
a:
  b: c
  x: y
```

##### Appending or overriding a config value:

```
$ python my_app.py ++a.b=y
a:
  b: y
```

```
$ python my_app.py ++a.x=y
a:
  b: c
  x: y
```

##### Removing a config value:

```
$ python my_app.py ~a.b
a: {}
```

```
$ python my_app.py ~a.b=c
a: {}
```

```
$ python my_app.py ~a.b=y
Could not delete from config. The value of 'a.b' is c and not y.
...
```

```
$ python my_app.py ~a.x
Could not delete from config. 'a.x' does not exist.
...
```

```
$ python my_app.py ~a.x=y
Could not delete from config. 'a.x' does not exist.
```

To summarize:

- Overriding a config value (`foo.bar=value`) works only if the given key is already present in the config
- Appending a config value (`+foo.bar=value`) works only if the given key not yet present in the config
- Appending or overriding a config value (`++foo.bar=value`) works whether or not the key is present in the config
- Removing a config value (`~foo.bar`, `~foo.bar=value`) works only if the given key or key-value pair is in the config.